# How to define an icon for a Gedit plugin written in Python

Tags: python, plugins, icons, pygtk, gedit

I am writing a Gedit plugin and created an icon for it as SVG (which of course can be exported to any format). How could I configure this plugin to show this icon in the plugin listing in `Edit > Preferences > Plugins` dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .plugin file accepts an `Icon` field -- as in this example:

```
[Gedit Plugin]
Loader=python
Module=TextWrap
IAge=2
Icon=gtk-ok
[... and so on ...]
```

Taken from the [TextWrap](http://hartmann-it-design.de/gedit/TextWrap/) plugin source.

To add a custom icon to an existing icon theme, place it in the appropriate folder -- i.e.

```
$prefix/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
```

as ptomato suggests, (where `$prefix` is probably `/usr` if you use linux) and then run

```
$ gtk-update-icon-cache $prefix/share/icons/hicolor
```

If the icon filename is `gedit-plug.svg`, it should now be available as `gedit-plug`. Note that I actually tested this on the `gnome` theme, rather than the `hicolor` theme.

Comment: I tried it. However, I have a custom icon, not a default GTK+ icon. How would I use this customized icon? Where should I put it? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like I'll have some annoying work to do because I want the plugin be easily installable to work _at least_ in Mac OS X, too. However, I got the icon in the Preferences dialog anyway, even in Mac OS X. I just registered the scalable icon and it looked pretty small but I'll try to solve solve this problem creating icons in various sizes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should install your icon in `$prefix/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps`: see the [Free Desktop Icon Theme Specificaton](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#install_icons).

Comment: Thanks! That was one of the steps missing in the process! I didn't like to do it but seems to be the solution...